# 404 Error Page not working for wrong dynamic pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Hello esteemed programmers,

First of all, my site was recently completed but the programmer has refused to render support citing that it was part of the contract. However, I just want to fix this singular problem and I can manage this site until future upgrade.

The sites pages have any of the formats below:

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=course&cid=xx
http://example.com/index.php?service&sid=xx
http://example.com/index.php?p=about-us
```

etc

I have a 404 error page in the location:

```
/include/404.php
```

and it will display as

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=404.php
```

Now I want to setup the 404 error page to display when a wrong page say:
http://example.com/index.php?p=about-us2.php

When a wrong page is entered, this is what comes up:

```
Warning: include(include/about-us2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hanpan5/public_html/testing/index.php on line 127

Warning: include(include/about-us2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hanpan5/public_html/testing/index.php on line 127

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'include/about-us2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/hanpan5/public_html/testing/index.php on line 127
```

I earlier added the 404 code to .htaccess however, it was affecting the pages on the blog hosting on `http://blog.example.com`
When the code was removed from .htaccess, the blog pages were working properly again.

I also noticed that there are some codes in index.php:

```
<div class="body">

        <?php include('include/menu.php'); ?>

        <?php
        if(!isset($_GET['p']) && @$_GET['p'] == '')
        {
        include('include/slider.php'); ?>

        <?php include('include/services.php'); ?>

        <?php include('include/strategy.php'); ?>

        <?php include('include/testimonial.php');
        include('include/twitterfeeds.php');
        }else
        {
          $p = $_GET['p'];
          include('include/'.$p.'.php');
        }
        ?>

        <?php include('include/footer.php'); ?>

    </div>
```

Is there anyway, I can add `include('include/404.php');` to the if statement above to help in the redirection. Or what can I do to solve this?

Eagerly awaiting your help.

Thank you very much in advance.

/** Edit 1 after @DaveG's first answer **/
Hello DaveG, this is my current implementation of your solution:

```
<div class="body">

        <?php

        include('include/menu.php');

        if(isset($_GET['p']))
            {
              $p = $_GET['p'];
              if(!file_exists('include/'.$p.'.php'))
              {
                header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                include('include/404.php');
                exit();
              }
            }
        else

        if(!isset($_GET['p']) && @$_GET['p'] == '')
        {
        include('include/slider.php'); ?>

        <?php include('include/services.php'); ?>

        <?php include('include/strategy.php'); ?>

        <?php include('include/testimonial.php');
        include('include/twitterfeeds.php');
        }
        else
        if(isset($_GET['p']))
        {
          $p = $_GET['p'];
          include('include/'.$p.'.php');
        }
        ?>

        <?php include('include/footer.php'); ?>

    </div>
```

Only index page (`/index.php`) is loading fully.

However, files ending with, for example, `/index.php?p=course&cid=13` and
`/index.php?p=abc` are not loading completely. Only the menu (`menu.php`) and footer (`footer.php`) are loading.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello @DaveG, please find my edit above. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: [after edit]: the problem is that you placed my code at the wrong place. It should be placed BEFORE everything else (so before the body-div and even before all the other headers.), and between `<?php` and `?>`. Also, the `else` must be removed just behind my code! My code is supplemental, but also the rest of the code should be executed, so no `else` there !

Comment: Thank you @DaveG. I will get back to you with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the file's existance with the `file_exists()`-function of php (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) in your index.php, after which you can return a 404-code with:

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); ?>
```

Take care: this must be done as the first output command, so first check the existance, then return header, and then continue the rest of the code !

In total:

```
if(isset($_GET['p']))
{
  $p = $_GET['p'];
  if(!file_exists('include/'.$p.'.php'))
  {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    include('include/404.php');
    exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DaveG. I've added the implementation of your solution to your answer. You can peer review it so that it will appear to others. Thank you very much and God bless you.